# Finding a subset in java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, subset

I am kind of familiar with what subsets are but I am having a hard time understanding how the below got two subset? Can someone point out how we got only two subsets. I just thought it would have more subsets.

A number, m, is defined as the size of some subsets S of A where each element covers an unbroken range of integers; that is to say, if you were to sort the elements in S, the difference between any elements j and j+1 is either 0 or 1. For example A = {5, 4, 4, 8, 8} gives us a subset {4, 4, 5} and {8,8}; these subsets have m values of 3 and 2 respectively.

Comment: Main question: If you think there should be more subsets, what other subsets do you think there should be?  Second question: what does this have to do with Java?  (I understand you may have to write a Java program for this, but so far you haven't asked a programming question).

Comment: Also, please note that in math, a "set" never has duplicate elements.  An element is either in a set or it isn't; it is never present multiple times.  This looks more like a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key statement is:

> the difference between any elements j and j+1 is either 0 or 1

So, for

> A={5,4,4,8,8}

A is sorted and as you traverse the elements, if the current element and next element (j and j+1) are within a difference of 0 or 1 of each other, they belong to the subset.

Hence, as you traverse:

```
A[0]=5 and A[1] = 4 : difference 1 - add to subset {5,4}
A[1]=4 and A[2]= 4 : difference 0 - add to subset {5,4,4}

A[2]=4 and A[3] = 8: difference is 4 - Start new subset {8}
A[3] = 8 and A[4] = 8] : difference is 0 - Add to subset {8,8}
```

Comment: Sir, you are awesome. Thank you very much for the clarification, I have been hung up on this for some time.